# Food nutrition for week long hike

Tags: nutrition

I'm going on a week long hike in Southern Spain. I envisage myself being away from civilisation max 3 days. What kind of food should I take at any one time?
There are infrequent farm houses and outbuildings.
A friend recommended dates, nuts, sultanas, carrot, cucumber, olives, salt, pepper for food? What do you think?

Comment: Count at least 3 to 5 liter water a day. It's crucial you know where a sources of water are.

Comment: The amount of water you need to carry depends completely on the weather and on how frequently you will have water sources available. You haven't told us what time of year this will be. The amount of water you need to carry on your back could be zero, or it could be some huge amount.

Comment: These seem like two separate questions to me: one about water, and the other about nutrition. The nutrition question doesn't seem to have anything to do with southern Spain in particular. The nutrition question is also very vague and general.

Comment: see also http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/3423/what-dried-vegetarian-foods-have-the-highest-ratio-of-calories-to-volume/3425#3425, http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/192/163, and food questions in general: http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it makes a big difference if you can bring a water filter with you and take advantage of verified sources of water, and by verified sources I mean water that you are 99.5% sure is going to be there when you are. You can't point out a stream on an old map and rely on it, this is your life source we're talking about.

If you want to prepare yourself for a completely self-sustained hike, the often-agreed upon minimum is 4 to 5 liters per day, and that's just for drinking. At 2 pounds per liter, trying to sustain yourself for more than 2 or 3 days without a water source you can filter from starts to sound like a bold endeavor. Especially if you want 6 or more liters per day in order to have a little extra.

Luckily, food is a little easier. If you had to go a couple days without because you didn't pack enough, in all likelihood you would survive even if you weren't happy about it. If you normally consume about 2000 calories per day, pack about that much and a little extra. For me personally this would mean about 4 freeze dried meals ( accounting for the water needed to rehydrate them ) plus a couple of snacks per day. It will of course be easier to bring lightweight and calorie dense foods but for the most part, you can bring whatever kind of food you please.

Comment: This is all valid and particularly important when you allow for the [notoriously unreliable Spanish maps](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/5249/good-quality-walking-maps-for-spain).

Comment: I have never used a water filter for anything other than as a last resort. I wouldn't recommend relying on a water filter because the probability is higher than you'll come across water that has something in it that the water filter doesn't filter. Where there are humans there is water. If there are wells there are humans to use them. there is very little water in general around where I am going.

Comment: It seems a lofty goal to plan on spending a week where you won't have access to water. Terrain features aside though, you've been misled about water filters. A good quality water filter purchased from a legitimate reseller is going to remove nearly anything you're worried about, bacteria and protozoa included.

Comment: I have an MSR miniworks, which I used occassionally over a 3 year period, including filtering water from mongolian bogs, the danube, puddles, rivers blah blah. After drinking the filtered water from the danube I tripped so hard I may as well have taken acid.

Comment: Okay, the Danube, when I say verified sources of water I also mean sources of water that aren't likely to be contaminated by entire cities.

Comment: @hillsons: *A good quality water filter purchased from a legitimate reseller is going to remove nearly anything you're worried about, bacteria and protozoa included.* Not true. A filter won't do anything about viruses.

Comment: @hillsons sometimes lessons are learned the hard way. About 3 mins after drinking the water I saw a dead dog floating in the water :) The Mongolian bog water experiment worked great though after the river went underground.

Comment: @BenCrowell indeed, there is some careful terminology at play, I should have said water *purifier*. If you're going someplace where viruses are a concern, you'll want a purifier designed to protect you from those of course.

Comment: ahh water purifier, yes I never used the tablets.